# how to setup filter in template

Tags: python, django

I want to setup filter in templates

I have filtered objects that I wanted, and now how can I setup the template?

So I can filter objects through dropdown?

What I'have done so far

```
@login_required
def list_jobs(request):
    assigned_jobs = Job.objects.filter(assign_to=request.user).order_by('-date_created')
    created_jobs = Job.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-date_created')
    completed_jobs = Job.objects.filter(completed=False).order_by('-date_completed')


    return render(request, 'jobs/list.html', {'created_jobs': created_jobs, 'assigned_jobs': assigned_jobs,
                                              'completed_jobs': completed_jobs})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example Something like this:

```
<select id="id">
    {% for i in assigned_jobs %} 
     <option value="{{ i.id }}">{{ i.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```